Issues with Calculating Building Characteristics, Footprint, Roof, and Facade Areas using Overpass API and OSM Data
I’m working on a project using Overpass API and OpenStreetMap (OSM) data to extract building characteristics such as footprint area, roof area, and facade areas in each direction. I'm also trying to determine if buildings are adjacent or standalone based on proximity.
Problems I'm Facing:
Overestimated Footprint and Roof Areas:
The calculated footprint and roof areas are consistently higher than expected. I'm projecting coordinates from WGS84 to UTM using pyproj, but the results seem inflated.
Facade Area Calculation Issues:
I’m calculating facade areas based on side lengths and building heights, accounting for adjacent buildings. However, the facade areas (especially East and West) appear to be overestimated, even when adjacent buildings are close.
Height Estimation:
I estimate heights using OSM height data (if available), building levels, or the gross floor area and footprint. Despite this hierarchy, height estimates sometimes seem inaccurate, leading to further issues with facade areas.
Adjacent vs Standalone Buildings:
I’m struggling to determine whether buildings in a given area are adjacent or standalone. I’m using a proximity threshold to identify adjacent buildings, but it doesn’t seem to work as expected.
Questions:
Is there a better way to handle coordinate projection or calculate building footprint/roof areas to avoid inflated values?
How can I improve the calculation of facade areas, especially for adjacent buildings?
Any suggestions on how to reliably determine if buildings are adjacent or standalone based on proximity?

If you have access to official building data, first of all I would compare it with OSM data and estimate the surface errors. While OSM data may be more accurate in terms of building counts, their area may be overstated, especially if it was drawn from aerial photos provided by Bing. That's a very common case. On the other hand, area of your interest might have been imported from official sources. Adjanced/standalone - maybe you should have look on overlapping walls (st_intersects, st_within may help).

I have tried to extract the data using the python script. I am using OSM overpass API to extract the data from OSM database. I have compared the result with OSM. I think in OSM database the tag Overlapping walls are not present, let me try with python script.

Duplicate post - same question was also posted on the OSM Community forum: https://community.openstreetmap.org/t/issues-with-calculating-building-characteristics-footprint-roof-and-facade-areas-using-overpass-api-and-osm-data/118671

WI am facing issue while calculating the the building is overestimating the facade for building having holes in middle. Here considering all the coordinates within building radious, holes considered as inner ring and for outer side of building as outer ring, then calculating the facade separately and adding to the total facade in each direction, for inner ring i am not considering the adjacency.
Any suggestions why i am not getting correct facade for building having hole in middle?
Thanks in advance.
